# Unexpected LayoutParams with an inflated LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I have an XML definition for a view that I am adding to a larger container view with addChild. It's based on a `LinearLayout` and looks basically like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="52dip"
android:background="@drawable/box_bg"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="onTreeBoxClick"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/box_photo"
    android:layout_width="45dip"
    android:layout_height="45dip"
        ...
/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
```

(Remainder omitted -- probably not relevant since it's basically working as designed)

When I create these views, I have found the following behaviors that seem odd to me:

1. Right after I inflate the view, getLayoutParameters() returns null.
2. After I call addChild() to add it to its parent, getLayoutParameters() returns a valid object.
3. Examining the LayoutParameters, I find both width and height set to -2 (WRAP_CONTENT), which is clearly not what I specified in the XML file.
4. When I look at the layout parameters of the enclosed ImageView, it reads out at the specified values.

Can anyone explain what is going on here? Why isn't my specified height being noticed?

This isn't really affecting me since the parent view is a custom view wherein I force the final dimensions of the children with MeasureSpec etc., but I'd like to understand this anyway!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You didn't provide some details which are important.

> 1) Right after I inflate the view, getLayoutParameters() returns null.

I would assume that you used this:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, null);
```

in this case the `LayoutInflater` can't make(at all) proper `LayoutParams` for the root `Linearlayout` because it doesn't know who is going to be its parent(so it can create the right type of `LayoutParams`). If you would use this:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, someOtherLayout, false/true);
```

then the root `LinearLayout` will have proper `LayoutParams` because it will see the type of `someOtherLayout` and create the `LayoutParams` from this information. You may want to provide a snippet of code to get a better answer if this is not what you currently do.

> 2) After I call addChild() to add it to its parent,
>   getLayoutParameters() returns a valid object.

I assume that you speak about the `addView()` method. The `addView()` method will check the `LayoutParams` of the view which is trying to add and if those `LayoutParams` are `null` then it will automatically assign that view a `LayoutParams` object returned by its `generateDefaultLayoutParams()` method.

> 3) Examining the LayoutParameters, I find both width and height set to
>   -2 (WRAP_CONTENT), which is clearly not what I specified in the XML file.

As I said at 2, the generated `LayoutParams` are coming from the `generateDefaultLayoutParams()` method which will return a `LayoutParams` instance as the parent was designed to do. For example, a `LinearLayout` with orientation `HORIZONTAL`(the default one) will return a `LayoutParams` instance with width/height set to `WRAP_CONTENT`.

> 4) When I look at the layout parameters of the enclosed ImageView, it
>   reads out at the specified values.

Because the `LayoutInflater` took care of this, as the `ImageView` it's in the interior of the layout and has a known parent from which the `LayoutInflater` can make the proper `LayoutParams`.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually figured out how this works. What I did to fix it was to use the 3rd argument of addView() to specify the desired LayoutParams for the view being added.

(And yes, I mistyped addView as addChild in my OP, thinking of the inverse of getChild() that I call in my custom view class.:-) )

Comment: when inflating with parent, you should use false as the third parameter. true did not work for me, params were still false. In short, do inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, someOtherLayout, false);